# Under modern law, was Jesus committing suicide by going to Gethsemane?

Tags: suicide

(Not sure if this should be in the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. I'm looking for a legal answer, though.)

For anyone unfamiliar with the context, Jesus is a historical person who is claimed to be divine, i.e., he had the ability to foresee the future. In the Bible, it's said that he knew he was going to get arrested if he went to Gethsemane (a garden within ancient Jerusalem), which in turn likely leads to his death. He went there anyway, and was indeed arrested and killed.

If we assume Jesus really had the ability to predict with a high degree of confidence that he will die if he goes to Gethsemane, and goes there anyway, does this qualify as suicide under modern law?

From what I've seen, the legal definition of '[suicide](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=2057)' is "intentional killing of oneself". This seems to suggest the answer is yes: Jesus knew he would probably die if he went to Gethsemane, and went there anyway. That seems superficially similar to me knowing I'd probably die if I jumped in front of a train. However the limits to this seems unclear, e.g. if I were to go to the site of an active mass shooting, and die, would that be suicide? If I were to sign up as a soldier, get deployed to some battle zone, and die, would that be suicide?

I'm most interested in where the lines between 'suicide' and 'not suicide' are drawn. If anyone knows what applied under ancient Roman law, I'm also interested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because That kind of hermeneutics isn't about the law.

Comment: @Jen According to modern law. If jurisdiction matters, assume Israel.

Comment: @Jen according to the Chief Justice of Israel? I cannot understand your question, it seems very weird. And from what I can see, there are quite a few legal implications of suicide, e.g. in the Netherlands (according to Wiki) "it is a crime to participate in the preparation for or execution of a suicide" -- so presumably one could argue that escorting Jesus to Gethsemane would be a crime.

Comment: @Jen Like, "would it be a crime to assist someone who can predict the future to go to a place where he knows he's going to die if he goes there"?

Comment: This goes to the definition of "kill"; for example, if you induce someone to go into a building at 11:00 and you know that the building will be demolished by an explosion at 11:05 that you otherwise have nothing to do with, have you killed the person?  The examples in the question concerning mass shootings and combat are perhaps not on point because the probability of death is rather lower in those cases.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you changed the premise of question from asking about the individual themselves, to someone else assisting after valid answers to the former were posted.

Comment: I also rolled it back to the version that matches the answers. If you want to ask a different question about assisting suicide then please ask a different question, don't completely overhaul one that invalidates answers already given...

Answer (score 3):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

You [have asked (revision 2)](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/101387/2):

> At what point does exposing yourself to risk qualify as suicide?

Intent is an essential element in the definition of suicide. Without intention that the act result in one's death, merely taking an action with the knowledge that it will increase one's chance of dying is not suicide. See *G.L. v. Saskatchewan Government Insurance*, [2023 SKAIA 6](https://canlii.ca/t/jxxtb).

The circumstances you describe are suicide only if the acts were taking with the *intention* of dying. Acts required by law (e.g. participating in a criminal trial process) do not qualify.

Comment: Intention seems crucial. In English law, the Coroners and Justice Act 2009 amending the Suicide Act 1961, for criminal liability for complicity in another’s suicide requires the "act was intended to encourage or assist suicide or an attempt at suicide."